# Deserialize response body with multiple "list[]" parameters to List in Java

Tags: java, http, deserialization

I would like to parse HTTP response body which is in following format:
`list[]=a&list[]=b&list[]=c&list[]=d&list[]=e` (there might be different number of elements)
to `List<String>`

I could just split the string by `&` and cut off `list[]=`, but I wonder if there is some more elegant way to do this (some kind of library that is able to deserialize it to List)

Comment: Are you using any framework?

Comment: No, just Java 11 SE + maven and some libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could just split the string by `&` and cut off `list[]=` [...]

You surely could do it. Just remember to [URL-decode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,java.nio.charset.Charset)) the parameters after splittig the query string ;)

> [...] but I wonder if there is some more elegant way to do this (some kind of library that is able to deserialize it to `List`)

If you are looking for a library, you could use Apache's [`URLEncodedUtils`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html):

```java
String queryString = "list[]=a&list[]=b&list[]=c&list[]=d&list[]=e";

List<NameValuePair> valuePairs = URLEncodedUtils.parse(queryString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Map<String, List<String>> queryParams = valuePairs.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(NameValuePair::getName, mapping(NameValuePair::getValue, toList())));

List<String> strings = queryParams.get("list[]");
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!